# Does Firefox support bidi-override in input[type="number"]?

Tags: html, css, firefox

Does Firefox support CSS attribute `unicode-bidi: bidi-override;` in `input[type="number"]`? As long as I can tell it doesn't but I'm wondering why because the Mozilla docs say that it's supported since Firefox 1.0. Here's jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9z1yrkse/. It works just fine with `input[type="text"]` and in other browsers.

Is there any other workaround instead of JS if I need to use `number` type?

Comment: It probably does not support because the implementation is specifically for numeric input, handled by the browser (it actually parses numbers etc.). You should probably find a different approach. Setting bidi-override for numeric input sounds like a practical joke rather than a useful thing to do.

Comment: It is not a practical joke. It has a legitimate use case. It is supposed to be implemented in an application where small children add, subtract or multiply two numbers on top of each other and you do these operations from right to left. Like you would do on the paper...